# webpack-dev-server v4 -window is not defined

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Hello I upgraded to Webpack 5 with the following versions:

```
  // package.json
  "webpack": "^5.11.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
```

I am starting the dev server with `webpack-dev-server -d source-map --mode=development` using the following configuration:

```js
// webpack.config.json
{
      entry,
      output: {
         filename: '[name].[fullhash].js',
         path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
         publicPath: '/',
      },
      resolve: {
         extensions: [
            '.js',
            '.jsx',
            '.ts',
            '.tsx',
         ],
         alias,
      },
      context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      devServer: {
         static: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
         public: 'localhost:3000',
         open: true,
         historyApiFallback: true,
         port: 3000,
         proxy: {
            '^/': 'http://localhost:3000'
         },
      },
      plugins: [
         new WebpackDotenv(),
         new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.html',
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            removeComments: true,
         }),
         new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'styles.css',
         }),
         new SVGSpritemapPlugin(
            '/assets/icons',
            {
               output: {
                  filename: 'spritemap.svg',
               }
            }
         ),
      ],
      stats: {
         assets: true,
         assetsSort: 'size',
         all: false,
         errors: true,
         colors: true,
         performance: true,
         timings: true,
      },
      optimization: {
         minimizer: [
            new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({}),
            new TerserPlugin({
               // Use multi-process parallel running to improve the build speed
               // Default number of concurrent runs: os.cpus().length - 1
               parallel: true,
               // Enable file caching
               extractComments: false,
            }),
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
               uglifyOptions: {
                  output: {
                     comments: false,
                  }
               }
            }),
         ],
      },
      module: {
         rules: [
            {
               test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
               exclude: /node_modules/,
               use: {
                  loader: 'swc-loader',
                  options: {
                     sync: true
                  }
               },
            },
            {
               // TODO: somehow the sourcemap is not being generated properly
               test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
               use: [
                  {
                     loader: 'style-loader',
                  },
                  {
                     loader: 'css-loader',
                     options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                     }
                  },
                  { loader: 'resolve-url-loader' },
                  {
                     loader: 'postcss-loader',
                     options: {
                        postcssOptions: {
                           plugins: [
                              require('autoprefixer'),
                           ],
                        },
                     },
                  },
                  {
                     loader: 'sass-loader',
                  }
               ],
            },
            {
               test: /\.css$/,
               use: [
                  MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                  'css-loader',
               ],
            },
            {
               test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
               use: {
                  loader: 'file-loader',
                  options: {
                     name: '[name].[ext]',
                     outputPath: 'fonts/',
                     publicPath: '/fonts',
                     esModule: false,
                  },
               },
            },
            {
               test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
               use: [
                  {
                     loader: 'file-loader',
                     options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'images/',
                        publicPath: '/images',
                     }
                  }
               ],
            },
         ],
      },
      devtool: 'source-map',
   }
```

Everything works fine, except that I receive the following error:

```js
// browser console
Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/default/index.js
```

The file in question can be found [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/client-src/default/index.js). Everything seems to be working fine, even with the error. But it feels bad to keep this error while developing.

Any suggestions on how to get rid of this error and provide the `window` object to the webpack dev server?

Comment: Can you share your `webpack.config.js` file?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added most of it.

Comment: If you have updated to webpack 5, I think you would serve your code via webpack cli directly `webpack serve`. Did you try that? If the error is still there, can you share your reproducible repo as well?

Comment: The error originates directly in the webpack-.dev-server. I don't want to use "webpack serve". I cannot show the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that, in my `entry` variable I got two things. One is the application itself, the other is its `service-worker`. The later in combination with the development mode is what causes the error. So I'm just checking now `process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development'` before I register my `service-worker`.

Not a real solution but sufficient for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you can patch `index.ts` and replace all the window calls with:

```js
(() => {
    if (typeof self !== 'undefined') {
        return self;
    } else if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        return window;
    } else if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
        return global;
    } else {
        return Function('return this')();
    }
})()
```

Then this should work.